# How do I get Apache to run from OSX Sierra 10.12.13?

Tags: apache-http-server, macos-sierra

I've made multiple searches for e.g. "apache Sierra", but haven't been able to find my issue.

I have a MacBook Pro running OSX Sierra 10.12.13, and it seems to have some version of Apache installed, but I can't connect on port 80 (or 443), either with a browser, or by running `telnet localhost 80`. If I run `apachectl restart`, it runs without reported error; if I run `apachectl stop` it runs without reported error; if I run `apachectl start` when I think Apache is running, it gives an error message, `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: service already loaded`. A `which apachectl` gives `/usr/sbin/apachectl`, so I believe I'm running OSX's native Apache and not a version pulled in from Homebrew.

What can/should I be doing so that Apache is running normally?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm having the opposite problem - cant get mine to stop loading

Comment: Do you know how to kill a process from the command line? Usually this sort of thing is preferably handled by `apachectl stop` or whatever, but `killall httpd` is a crowbar that may be useful. (Running a `chmod -x` or `chmod 0000` on something you suspect is respawning might stop respawning.)